# asp.net mvc datannotation password validate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how can i validate a password with asp.net mvc dataanotation, the password must be between 6 and 16 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the StringLengthAttribute in data annotations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=VS.95).aspx